# In the below i get a memory leak for the NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

in The above code i am creating a NSMutableURLRequest and then i am loading a webview with this request.But it gives me moemory leak saying the following :-

1) Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'request' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning message says, use release statement for your request as,

```
 MutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
```

or you can use

```
 MutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

If you are not using ARC, you need to release/autorelease any params created by allocating memory. One way to avoid this is by switching to ARC.

Comment: But if i use autorelease it will become more prone to a crash as we never know when will the autorelease pool get emptied

Comment: But i dont understand where should we actually use autorelease?

Comment: No, ideally loadRequest should retain it. If you are confused like that, you can go for `[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: ` method. In that case you dont need to provide autorelease since you dont own it by doing allocation.

Comment: @BhartiSyal, autorelease is used when you have to hold the object for some more time and release it later such as returning an allocated param from a method. In the receiver you should retain it. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html for more details

Comment: @BhartiSyal The web view will retain it for its own operations, so you don't need to worry about it being prone to crash. Look at `[request retainCount]` before and after the `loadRequest` and you'll see that this is the case. The rule of manual memory management is that if you create it (specifically, with a method that begins with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`), you own it and you are responsible to `release` it (or `autorelease`). If you don't create object using method starting with one of those four prefixes, you _must not_ `release` or `autorelease`.

Comment: Also see the this section of [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

Comment: @Rob load request of retain before 1
load request of retain after 2 But even though i gave autorelease still the retain count increased to 2

Comment: @BhartiSyal, loadReqeust will retain and release it itself. As Rob said, you have to release it only when you are using `alloc, new, copy, mutableCopy or retain`. So it will be +1 and 0 after the use.

Comment: If you're saying that you saw the `retainCount` of the `request` go from +1 to +2, that is your proof that the `UIWebView` retained it. The `UIWebView` now has responsibility for eventually releasing its `retain` on the `request`, but that ain't your problem (and it does it fine). But you're responsible for the `release`/`autorelease` that to match your `alloc`.

Comment: @Rob,@ACB i didn't understand why the count increased to 2 even after autorelease

Comment: It's be cause `autorelease` is a _deferred_ `release`. The release happens when your methods yield back to the operating system's run loop.

Comment: @BhartiSyal, autorelease wont decrement the count immediately. It will take some time before the memory pool is emptied.

Comment: ok ,but in case of release the count gets decreased immediately. Thanks @Rob,@ABC

Comment: The [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) that ACB and I referred you to is required reading and is surprisingly dense. Don't be surprised if you have to go through it more than once. But it addresses many of these sorts of questions.